# How often would I refresh the offline access token in a web app?

Tags: oauth-2.0, youtube-api, access-token, refresh-token

Let's say I create a simple YouTube bot, sending thumbs up to some videos. I have several YouTube accounts connected to my web app. We can assume here that in practice, there is at least one video to like every 5-10 minutes, but usually more often. My web app runs every 1 minute to fetch if there are new videos to like. If it finds them, it likes them all.

This is a dummy example, but I'd like to understand how **in reality** we refresh offline access tokens.

So I connect each of my Google accounts to my Google app via consent screen with `access_type=offline` and I store all my refresh tokens, one per account. Now, when would it make sense to get the access tokens, which in Google case live for 1 hour? Here are some strategies I can think of:

1. Refresh access token with every request, which is once per one minute for every account. Don't store the access token anywhere but in a variable. The next cron flow (one minute later) will just generate new access token.
2. Store access tokens' lifetime and with every new flow, check if it's fresh enough to work with it, giving it some margin. For example, if it has at least 3 minutes left, use it. Otherwise, generate new one and use it.
3. Always try to use the access token and only refresh it on error. That means, don't keep track of anything, just brute force using whatever you have. If there's access denial, refresh the token.

Do any of these strategies make more sense than others? How is it done in real world web apps?

Comment: Related  - https://security.stackexchange.com/q/119371

Comment: Not sure how that article about security is relevant here. The question was rather what is absolutely necessary to store in this case. If I don't need to store access tokens, I would rather not.